# How can you tile this checkerboard with trominoes?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Ok, so define a tromino as a $1$x$3$ tile. If a corner is removed from an $8$x$8$ board, is it possible to tile it with these trominoes? So far, I have concluded that you would need $21$ trominoes to tile the remaining $63$ squares. If you color the squares three different colors, it is possible to have an equal number of each. I alternated the diagonals for each color. Theoretically, a tiling should be possible right? I have been trying to find such a tiling, but each time I end up with three squares that cannot fit the shape of the given tromino. Are there any possible tilings? Thanks.

Comment: Try coloring with the diagonals in the other direction.

Comment: If you color the board by diagonals, you get $22$ of the color used for the squares adjacent to the missing corner, $21$ of the next color, and $20$ of the third.

Comment: I colored it in such a way that you have $21$,$21$,$22$ of each color and then removing one square from the color with $22$ squares gives $21$ squares to each color.

Comment: Ok so according to the link given from @MateusSampaio, there does not exist a tiling. Thanks.